# Why can't I sell my Steam Trading Cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I have joined the Steam Trading Card Beta group, and have gathered 3 cards from CS:GO and FTL. When I open my inventory and try to click "Sell," the option is greyed-out. It says that since I recently changed my password, I can't use the marketplace until 2013-06-27.

However, the current date of me posting this is 2013-06-28, a day after I was supposed to be able to use the marketplace. Why can't I sell my cards?

I tried restarting Steam, but to no avail.

Comment: @Sconibulus Thanks, you should add that as an answer, and if it works, I'll make it the official answer.

Comment: @Sconibulus Yes, but oddly, the time of day when the "steam day" changed for me was around 10 PM Pacific Time.

Comment: @Sconibulus Ah! That must be it. Feel free to edit that into your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Valve days change over at 10 AM Pacific Time, so an expiration date of the 27th implies that the moratorium will expire sometime between 10AM Pacific on the 27th, and 10AM Pacific on the 28th.

The duration of the moratorium is 5 full days, so if your password is changed at Noon UTC, you will be able to trade again at Noon UTC.